# TLS Certificate pinning in gRPC

Tags: ios, objective-c, grpc, certificate-pinning

Using the Objective-C gRPC library, how do I implement TLS certificate pinning?

Bonus question: how do I achieve this using `GRPCcall2`, and **not** the deprecated `GRPCcall`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gRPC doesn't support TLS certificate pinning, but you can set the root certificate in `GRPCMutableCallOptions`

```
/**
 * PEM format root certifications that is trusted. If set to nil, gRPC uses a list of default
 * root certificates.
 */
@property(copy, readwrite, nullable) NSString *PEMRootCertificates;
```

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/objective-c/GRPCClient/GRPCCallOptions.h#L331

Comment: Can you perhaps provide an example of setting multiple certificates on this property? Just wondering how the list would be formatted as a string.

Comment: @PhlippieBosman example with 2 certs: https://gist.github.com/marcinmierzejewski1024/aefbbfa0b574cad1c9ec5587cca95fbe